# Old Sci-Fi story with towers that beam energy to airships

Tags: story-identification

This is a very old sci fi story as I recall, it might be from as early as the 1930s and I think I read it in an anthology.  I thought it was the Isaac Asimov "Before the Golden Age" anthology but it seems not.

Anyway this story had as I recall something of a steampunk feel to it but not really steampunk.

The one bit I can remember distinctly is that there were airships and that they did not carry fuel or anything, instead they received beams of energy from a tower that ran their engines, so they couldn't go out of range of the tower and the plot I believe naturally involved an effort to disable the tower(s).

I remember the story being somewhat long and involved and convoluted.  It may possibly have been also been a kind of alternative reality story, like the main character shrinks down to the size of an atom and the world where all this takes place is on the head of a pin or something.

Answer (score 7):

You are actually describing two stories: "Submicroscopic" and its sequel "Awlo of Ulm," though the beamed power aircraft are only brought out in the second.

As you thought, they are indeed included in "Before the Golden Age." Very cool anthology. It's what got me interested in retro sci-fi.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was trying to read a synopsis of the stories in that anthology and nothing seemed to ring a bell.